# This kind of things has or have?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> This kind of devices (have/has) become very popular among the young.

Which form of *to have* is used in cases like this?

Comment: So does this question have a valid answer after all?

Answer (score 10):

I have always wanted to do it your way too but unfortunately, in respect to grammar, it works the other way:

- This (kind,type,sort) of thing
- These (kinds,types,sorts) of things

A workaround for plural (formal) is:

- Things of this (kind, type, sort)

A workaround for singular (formal) is:

- A (an) thing of this (kind, type, sort)

In your case you'll be correct by saying:

1. These kinds of devices have become popular among the young.
2. Devices of this kind have become popular among the young.

The old pattern "**these kind of things**" comes from "**kind**" being an unmarked plural noun (like deer or folk). It is in use in PDE, but grammarians mark it as ungrammatical. This pattern was used by Shakespeare.

- I like these kind of questions.

This new pattern "**these kinds of things**" was an adaptation based on singular/plural agreement.

In informal English "**this kind of things**" can often be met.

Comment: I've got it: either "this kind of thing" or "these kinds of things". But what can you say about the construction "These kind of things" that Andrew mentioned? I admit I never thought it would be a correct option.

Comment: @Voli I've updated my answer.

Comment: I fixed a couple of inconsequential typos but is "adoptation" supposed to be _adoption_ or _adaptation_?

Comment: @DavidRicherby  perhaps it's a portmanteau?  :)

Comment: @DavidRicherby I appreciate your help, thank you. I've corrected "**adoptation**" to "**adaptation**".

Comment: It would be pleasing if you downvoters commented.

Answer (score 9):

As written your example sentence is confusing because it's already incorrect.  The pronoun needs to agree with the noun, and then the verb agrees with both:

> **This** kind of **device** ***has*** become popular
>
> **These** kind of **devices** ***have*** become popular

You might have thought that the pronoun "this" refers to *kind*, not *devices*, and should be singular.  Actually "kind of devices" is a short *noun phrase*, and is considered singular or plural based on some *defining* noun in the phrase:

> These **kind** of questions show how quirky English can be.  (all the questions are of the same kind)
>
> These **kinds** of questions show how quirky English can be.  (multiple different kinds of questions)

Edit:  As stangdon pointed out, with a noun phrase like "bag of oranges" the key noun is "bag" not "oranges".  One of the nouns in the phrase will define whether the phrase is singular or plural:

> **These** bags of oranges **are** heavy.
>
> **This** bag of oranges **is** heavy.
>
> **This** sort of protest **is** against regulations.
>
> **These** varieties of fruit **are** tropical.

That being said, you wouldn't use a plural modifying noun with a singular noun. For example "this kinds of device" would be incorrect.  In order to have multiple *kinds*, you need multiple *devices*.

Comment: That bit about short noun phrases doesn't really sound right to me.  Would you say "This bag of oranges **are** heavy"?  I absolutely wouldn't.

Comment: @stangdon  Yeah, you're right.  So it's not determined by the final noun in the phrase, but it's still determined by *some* noun in the phrase.  Is there an overarching principle here?

Comment: Well, I think that we have to look at what's the main noun in the phrase and what's part of a prepositional phrase.  "This kind of flooper(s) is/are grombly" is a bit awkward because what we really mean is that the floopers themselves are grombly, not so much that the *kind* is grombly.  Probably the best thing to do is leave everything in the singular.

Comment: @stangdon "**This bag of oranges**" doesn't obey the same rule as "**this kind of thing**". Here the sentence reads as "**This [bag of oranges]**".

Comment: I would never say "these kind of questions." Sounds stilted. 
I would say "this kind of question" which basically means "this question, and others of the same kind."

Comment: @SovereignSun - Why do you think they don't obey the same rule?

Comment: @Andrew I think the overarching principle is that the pronoun matches the first noun of the noun phrase. I also think that means your **"These kind of devices have become popular"** sentence is incorrect. It should be **"These kinds of devices have become popular"** (or even **"These kinds of device have become popular"**). You could just as easily say **"These kinds have become popular"**; the **"of devices"** is really just for clarity.

Comment: @LordFarquaad  I'm sorry but you are simply incorrect.  "These kind of devices" is perfectly valid English.  There are many, many examples, but for maximum pedantry I'll quote from *King Lear*: "**These kind of knaves** I know, which in this plainness / Harbor more craft and more corrupter ends /
Than twenty silly-ducking observants / That stretch their duties nicely."

Comment: @Andrew I mean, Shakespeare was pretty well known for throwing grammar and English to the wind. The guy made up the word "elbow". **"These kind of devices"** is just not right, because it requires "these" to be the pronoun to "devices". Try making a [parse tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree) that puts "devices" at the top; the "of" makes it impossible. A preposition requires a noun, and "devices" is the only one available. The structure should go **[pronoun][noun][prepositional phrase]**, and you simply can't get that with **"These kind of devices"**

Comment: @Andrew If **"kind of"** could be treated as an adjective then what you're saying is true, as **[pronoun][adjective][noun]** is still a noun phrase ("These blue devices"). But I don't think we can treat it that way...

Comment: @LordFarquaad  Well, if Shakespeare isn't enough, try this:  https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70341/these-sort-of-things-is-it-grammatical-2-670-000-hits-on-google .  The ultimate gauge of grammar is *usage* -- if a phrase is (relatively) common, then it is grammatical.

Comment: @stangdon I've listed Oxford, Cambridge, BBC, and a few other sources and it says there that the rule is for classifications (like kind, type, sort, class, variety). For the rest it works the simple way: you take the noun phrase as a whole nit as separate entities. So for instance in "**This bag of oranges**" you take the whole noun phrase **bag of oranges** as a singular entity, but the verb still always agrees with **this/that** or **these/those**.

Comment: @barbecue "**These kind of things**" is perfectly okay. Notice that many famous people used it and many still use it. The idea here is to set multiple things under one classification whereas if you say "**These kinds of things**" you set each thing out of many under its own classification. One thing=one classification, so we have as many classifications as there are things. This is easy to understand. The problem is with "**This kind of things**" which, regardless of being ungrammatic, is quite logical: Here again multiple things come under one classification. -

Comment: @barbecue But we, instead of referring to the things of that class, refer to the class itself. So basically we get **this kind is** instead of **things of this kind are**.

Comment: @stangdon Your example with **floopers** is a good one. Indead we should refer to the things themselves and not the classification of those things. If we take "**This kind of doors**" we end up referring to "**this kind**", whereas we want to refer to "**the doors of this kind**". I can't see a possible scenario where one would want to speak about the classification.

Comment: @Andrew I agree that usage is a trump card over technical grammar, but you've gotta see how it might be confusing to an English learner to see **"The pronoun needs to agree with the noun, and then the verb agrees with both"**, then an example where it doesn't, right?

Comment: @SovereignSun Many famous people say all kinds of idiotic stuff, that proves nothing. "These kinds of things" does NOT mean "these things each divided into their own unique kind." That's ridiculous. "These kinds of things" means "These things and others of their kinds. Two or more things, and other things which are "of a kind with" them. Meaning like them.

Comment: Nobody talking about "kinds of things" has any of this nonsense in mind. They just want to express that there is a thing, and there are other things which are like that thing, and they're talking about those things. It's that simple.